# Variable in where clause arcpy.Select

Tags: arcpy, sql, select-by-attribute, loop, where-clause

I'm trying to set up a loop that includes using items in the array along with string text to populate the where clause.  I'm getting the invalid sql expression for the clause.  Here's what I have so far.

```
# Flight Levels array

 flightLevelsArray = ["FL290", "FL300", "FL310", "FL320", "FL330", "FL340", "FL350", "FL360", "FL370", "FL380", "FL390", "FL400", "FL410", "FL420"]

queryFL290 = "FL IN ('FL285', 'FL286', 'FL287', 'FL288', 'FL289', 'FL290', 'FL291', 'FL292', 'FL293', 'FL294')"
queryFL300 = "FL IN ('FL295', 'FL296', 'FL297', 'FL298', 'FL299', 'FL300', 'FL301', 'FL302', 'FL303', 'FL304')"

for flightLevel in flightLevelsArray:
flightLevelField = "!"+flightLevel+"!"
rangeToQuery = "query"+flightLevel

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(out_layer_file, "ADD_TO_SELECTION", rangeToQuery)
```

Comment: BTW this was working before the loop when I directly referenced the where clause, so the syntax is good there.

Comment: Your whereclause `rangeToQuery` is meaningless. On the first iteration it would be "query!FL290!".. Have a look at the help file for this tool and look at the code samples.

Comment: It will also be useful for you, as you debug this, to print the output to see what you are getting in the **rangeToQuery** variable. As @Hornbydd indicates, you can see you are not passing in a valid query.

Comment: @Hornbydd rangeToQuery actually returns queryFL290 on the first iteration, which is good.  But this is a string instead of the variable I've assigned.  How would I make this a valid input?

Comment: try eval(queryFL290)

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to call a different variable based on each value in the flightLevelsArray. For this, you should use a dictionary--not try to dynamically call variable names.

However, it doesn't appear that's actually what you need anyway. I would assume that you're trying to construct a series of queries, like this:

```
FL IN ('FL285', 'FL286', 'FL287', 'FL288', 'FL289', 'FL290', 'FL291', 'FL292', 'FL293', 'FL294')

FL IN ('FL295', 'FL296', 'FL297', 'FL298', 'FL299', 'FL300', 'FL301', 'FL302', 'FL303', 'FL304')

FL IN ('FL305', 'FL306', 'FL307', 'FL308', 'FL309', 'FL310', 'FL311', 'FL312', 'FL313', 'FL314')

FL IN ('FL315', 'FL316', 'FL317', 'FL318', 'FL319', 'FL320', 'FL321', 'FL322', 'FL323', 'FL324') ...
```

That would mean that you have a field named `FL` and within it are values like `FL285` and `FL307`.
If so, you would want to iterate over the ranges of values, rather than typing out each range.

Try:

```
# Iterate over values between 290 and 420, incrementing by 10
for fl in range(290, 430, 10):
    # Compile a list of 'FLxxx' for each number from 5 below to 4 above the
    #   flight level
    values = ["'FL{}'".format(v) for v in range(fl - 5, fl + 5)]
    # Construct the full query
    query = 'FL IN ({})'.format(', '.join(values))
    # Continue on with whatever processing you do with that query
    arcpy.SelectLay...
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with your flightLevelField variable, since you never seem to use it. Based on the ambiguity of the code, I would suspect that your field isn't actually named `FL` and/or that your field values don't have the "FL" prefix; if it is and they are, then you may want to reconsider the data design.

Comment: Yes, the field name is "FL" and the values contain the "FL" prefix.  But I am selecting the values in this field by groups, i.e. FL285-FL294 to compare a related field named "FL290".with yet another field containing data.  The flightLevelField variable is used in a separate sql expression, so I didn't need to include that.  I will try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:  I created a dictionary called flightLevelsArray referencing the flight levels string to search and the associated query for the where clause statement.  I used UpdateCursor instead of Calculate Field:

```
flightLevelsArray = {"FL290":"FL IN ('FL285', 'FL286', 'FL287', 'FL288', 'FL289', 'FL290', 'FL291', 'FL292', 'FL293','FL294')", 
etc for each flight level range
}

for flightLevel in flightLevelsArray:
 calcFields = ['FL', flightLevel]
 queryFL = flightLevelsArray[flightLevel]
 cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(out_layer_file, calcFields, queryFL)
 for row in cursor:
# Calculate values for each FL
  #do calculations
  cursor.updateRow(row)
  cursor.reset(row)
```